# Loading PCM Array into SoundPool

Tags: android, audio

I'm generating my own synthetic sounds stored in byte arrays encoded in 16 bit PCM format. I would like to load these arrays into `SoundPool` to help manage how and when theses sounds are played.

However, `SoundPool`'s `load` methods all seem to refer to resource files, e.g., .mp3, .wav etc., and not an already existing byte array of PCM data. Is there any way to load an existing byte array of PCM data into a `SoundPool` object?

I thought about extending `SoundPool` and adding my own `load` method, but the `SoundPool` source, understandably, makes many native calls, so it's not clear how it actually performs the loading.

If not I'll have to create my own `SoundPool` class.

Comment: Why do you not use `AudioTrack`？

Comment: Add a WAV header, write the result to a file and then load the file into a `SoundPool`?

Comment: @EricLiu - If I have to write my own class I will probably use `AudioTrack`. However, it's the way `SoundPool` prioritizes sounds that I'm interested in.

Comment: @Michael - Yes. This is a possibility. It just seems a rather roundabout way since the `SoundPool` is just going to convert it back.